Packaging my python "textual" library powered text-user-interface, and its requirements.txt libraries, into a "1-click" executable
I have built a pretty simple text-user-interface with the python textual library, for a third-party command line interface library I am utilizing. My current objective is to package the TUI as a binary/executable. I want the executable to be "1-click", meaning I don't need the end-user to install any libraries (the CLI or textual), or even python itself honestly (even though that should be very uncommon).
The basic project hierarchy is like so:
TUI
├── requirements.txt
├── application
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── frontend.py
│   │   ├── style.tcss
│   ├── back
│   │   ├── backend.py

The CLI I am building the TUI for is a part of the PyPi repository, and is including in my TUI requirements.txt, so it should be easy to add to the packaged executable. For even further reference, here is a link to the CLI.
How would I go about doing something like this? Any advice is much appreciated!
I have already attempted using PyInstaller using the following command:
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data 'application/app/style.tcss:application/app/' --name "TUI v0.1.0 (MacOS)" application/main.py

However, it doesn't seem to package the CLI with the TUI. When I attempt to run the TUI it hits my internal error check for whether the TUI can be called, and errors out. Does anybody have prior experience packaging a small textual project with additional python library requirements like this? If so, I would greatly appreciate some advice on whether a different packaging library worked better for you, or if I may be doing something wrong with PyInstaller.

I tried it once before... Pyinstaller does not seem to take tcss files properly. You have to copy the contents of tcss file into the py files where you specified as path(like in the official docs where the CSS is within these """ """").
Hopefully this works for you too.
